# Website on philosophical knowledge

Tags: knowledge-representation

Here http://mathonline.wikidot.com/ you can see a great website where some mathematical knowledge is organized, and I am wondering if there is a similar website for philosophy. Thank you so much.

Comment: http://www.philosophypages.com perhaps...?

Comment: [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/) is quite detailed and organised

Comment: What about Wolfram's wiki?

Comment: Here is [PhilPapers taxonomy of philosophy](https://philpapers.org/utils/struct.pl) that organizes philosophical publications by topic. But no pictures.